# Selenium error 'Permission denied to access property'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Is there a way to resolve the 'Permission denied to access property' error?

I have the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/ xxx /Documents/Selenium/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https:/unsplash.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

and the last line, with 'getPageSource()' is causing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
Permission denied to access property "__raven_wrapper__"
```

(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I've seen in another question ([Permission denied to access property "document"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820856/permission-denied-to-access-property-document)) that to overcome this error they use the chrome driver instead.

Is it really a problem with the FirefoxDriver or is there a way around?

Thanks