# Error: Permission denied to access property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, iframe, cors, cross-domain, addeventlistener

I am trying to open a window with url passed of a pdf downloaded. but it throws error "Error: Permission denied to access property 'addEventListener'". The error show up in firefox, in chrome it is working fine.

I googled and figured out it is due to the cross domain policy.Given below is my code

```
var printWindow = window.open(fileUrl, 'Print', 'left=0, top=0, width=' + pdfResolution.w + ', height=' + pdfResolution.h + ', toolbar=0, resizable=0');

                printWindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
                    printWindow.print();
                }, true);
```

Also, the fileUrl generated is like blob:https%3A//domain.com/e597b770-8d11-48ab-b458-782af519be27

Suggest how can i surpass this restriction so that i open the print preview for the downloaded pdf.

Answer (score 0):

After a week I disable marionette for FF (java):

`capability.setCapability("marionette", false);`

It's repair **everything**.